# Name (or refer) a specialized template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I decided to use the following pattern to combine various types of objects and their configs automatically:

```
enum class Type { Car, Person };

template< Type TYPE >
struct Object;

template< Type TYPE >
struct ObjectConfig;

template<>
struct ObjectConfig< Type::Car >
{
};

// Version 1
template<>
struct Object< Type::Car >: public ObjectConfig< Type::Car > // How could I avoid this duplication???
{
};

// Version 2
template<>
struct Object< Type::Car >
{
    static constexpr Type myType{ Type::Car }; // How could I avoid this duplication???
    ObjectConfig< myType > m_params;
};
```

It is intended to be error-proof and automatic, but I can not avoid writing the enum value twice (which is error prone and non-automatic at all).
I would like to write something similar (so I would like to refer the specialized parameter somehow):

```
template< Type TYPE >
struct Object;

template<>
struct Object< Type::Car >: public ObjectConfig< TYPE >
{
};
```

Is there any trick I could use to achieve something similar?

Thank you in advance!

Please find the detailed code [here (code)](https://godbolt.org/z/hh4V9r)

Comment: Something like this? `template <Type T=Type::Car>
    struct Object : public ObjectConfig< T > {
    };
    
    
    Object<> a;`

Comment: As I see the code you suggest is not a template specialization but a redefinition with a default value. There will be of course many specializations (Car, Person, etc...), so a default value is not suitable.

Comment: then use a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an universal solution.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Type { Car, Person };

template< Type TYPE, typename T = void >
struct Object
{
    static_assert( sizeof( T ) == 0, "Not supported" );
};

template< Type TYPE >
struct ObjectConfig;

template<>
struct ObjectConfig< Type::Car >
{
};


// Version 1 - solved
template< Type TYPE >
struct Object< TYPE, std::enable_if_t< TYPE == Type::Car > >: public ObjectConfig< TYPE > // No emum duplication
{
};

// Version 2 - solved
template< Type TYPE >
struct Object< TYPE, std::enable_if_t< TYPE == Type::Person > >
{
    ObjectConfig< TYPE > m_params; // No emum duplication
};
```

You can check the full solution [here (code)](https://godbolt.org/z/D8dPvd)

Comment: I think this version is error-proof, the users cannot mess it up with tricky instantiations :) The code seems to be compact at least for me :) Please add your thoughts and comments, I will accept this version as an answer unless you find a flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for both versions although it is a little bit complicated.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Type { Car, Person, Truck };

template<Type TYPE>
struct ObjectConfig;

template<>
struct ObjectConfig<Type::Car>
{ };

template<>
struct ObjectConfig<Type::Person>
{ };

template<Type T>
struct FakeDependency: public std::false_type
{ };

template<Type TYPE, Type DELEGATED_TYPE = TYPE, typename DUMMY = typename std::enable_if<DELEGATED_TYPE == TYPE>::type >
struct Object;

template<Type TYPE, Type DELEGATED_TYPE, typename DUMMY>
struct Object
{
    static_assert( FakeDependency<DELEGATED_TYPE>::value, "Not supported!" );
};

template<Type DELEGATED_TYPE, typename DUMMY>
struct Object<Type::Car, DELEGATED_TYPE, DUMMY>
{
    ObjectConfig<DELEGATED_TYPE> m_params;
};

template<Type DELEGATED_TYPE, typename DUMMY>
struct Object<Type::Person, DELEGATED_TYPE, DUMMY> : public ObjectConfig<DELEGATED_TYPE>
{ };

int main() {
    Object<Type::Car> c;
    Object<Type::Person> p;
    //Object<Type::Truck> t;  // Static assertion
    //Object<Type::Car, Type::Person> cp; // template 3 (enable_if) invalid
}
```

You can check the [full code](https://godbolt.org/z/H3hVAx)

I introduced a template that shadows the first one by having it as a default value. You can use it both inside the class and for inheritance.

I added safety checks to prevent instantiate your object with different template parameters: `Object<Type::Car, Type::Person>`. To do this I added a third template parameter which is a type template with an `enable_if` as a default value. You will get a compile-time error if you try to instantiate an object with different template parameters. The second check prevents you to have objects like this: `Object<Type::Car, Object::Car, int>` because in this case, the compiler will fall back to the primary template which is going to assert.

Without having the safety checks it becomes more simple:

```
enum class Type { Car, Person, Truck };

template<Type TYPE>
struct ObjectConfig;

template<>
struct ObjectConfig<Type::Car>
{ };

template<>
struct ObjectConfig<Type::Person>
{ };

template<Type TYPE, Type DELEGATED_TYPE = TYPE>
struct Object;

template<Type DELEGATED_TYPE>
struct Object<Type::Car, DELEGATED_TYPE>
{
    ObjectConfig<DELEGATED_TYPE> m_params;
};

template<Type DELEGATED_TYPE>
struct Object<Type::Person, DELEGATED_TYPE> : public ObjectConfig<DELEGATED_TYPE>
{ };

int main() {
    Object<Type::Car> c;
    Object<Type::Person> p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think the version with the safety checks is not entirely safe, the checks can be bypassed with the following code:
Object<Type::Car, Type::Person, void > c2;

Answer (score -1):

If possible you can work by composition instead of inheritance. Create an inner templated config Class and add a member to it.

```
template< Type TYPE>
struct ObjectByComposition
{
    template<typename Type TYPE >
    struct Config{
        /*Whatever*/
    };

    Config<TYPE> m_Config;
};

ObjectByComposition< Type::Car > m_params;
```

Edit after OP answer : the fact that is is an inner class is not mandatory off course , the important thing is to make the member m_config templated with the T type.

```
template< Type TYPE  >
struct ObjectByComposition
{
    ObjectConfig< TYPE> m_Config;
};

ObjectByComposition< Type::Car > m_params;
```

Comment: I need to explicitly and independently specialize both Object and ObjectConfig classes (they have their own class hierarchy but I simplified it) - this is why an inner class is not suitable. As you can see in my original question "Version 2" uses composition, but it does not solve my problem (I must write the enum value twice).

Comment: what is important is that the member m_config is templated. it does not need to be an inner class...

Comment: if is still not enough (if several type of ObejctConfig can be used) , then you need template template parameter for ObjectConfig and provide a default value.

Comment: From my previous comment: "I need to explicitly and independently specialize both Object and ObjectConfig classes" 
So I need to specialize - in your version - ObjectByComposition class, because a Car type has different functions than a Person type. My whole question is about specialization, I do not know how could your code handle this situation. I will provide a full example in the question, could you please improve it with your version?

Comment: the question you should answer is : will any specialization of the class Object for a given type T can have a config which is not the one provided by specialization of Config<T> ?  if yes, then you can´t do what you aim at, if no, then my answer is fine. Nothing prevent you in what I said to specialize config. If you want to also specialize Object, than you might do a templated class BaseObject implementing what i suggest and a derive Object class from this one. that then you specialize if needed.

Comment: Dear @sandwood, any specialization of Object uses the same specialization of ObjectConfig, so your suggestion is suitable. The key of my problem is the following: "If you want to also specialize Object, than you might do a templated class BaseObject implementing what i suggest and a derive Object class from this one. that then you specialize if needed." The circle closes: If I specialize Object and I would like to descend from the templated BaseObject I must write the enum twice as well:
`template<> class Object< Type::Car >: public BaseObject< Type::Car >` - this was my original problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think I've solved the version 2 kind of problems:

```
enum class Type { Car, Person };

template< Type TYPE >
struct Object;

template< Type TYPE >
struct ObjectConfig;

template<>
struct ObjectConfig< Type::Car >
{
};

template< typename T >
struct ObjectTypeResolver
{
};

template< template< Type > class OBJ_T, Type TYPE >
struct ObjectTypeResolver< OBJ_T< TYPE > >
{
    static constexpr auto value{ TYPE };
};

// Version 1 - still unsolved
//template<>
//struct Object< Type::Car >: public ObjectConfig< Type::Car > // How could I avoid this duplication???
//{
//};

// Version 2 - solved
template<>
struct Object< Type::Car >
{
    static constexpr Type myType{ ObjectTypeResolver< Object >::value }; // No emum duplication
    ObjectConfig< myType > m_params;
};
```

You can check the full code [here (code)](https://godbolt.org/z/xDUuRy)

I utilized the following:
C++17 standard 17.7.1  Locally declared names

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause 12). The injected-class-name can be used
>   as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template
>   template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the
>   elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration, it
>   refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to
>   the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in<>.
>
> Within the scope of a class template specialization or partial
>   specialization, when the injected-class-name is used as a type-name,
>   it is equivalent to the template-name followed by the
>   template-arguments of the class template specialization or partial
>   specialization enclosed in<>.

This is why it cannot be applied on version 1 kind of problems: inheriting list is out of the scope of the class template.

That part of the question is still open.